# Ubuntu installation always crashes while creating ext4 file system

Tags: live-usb, ssd, freeze, crash

I am currently trying to install Xubuntu with my 128GB USB stick on my 120 GB SSD.
*These are my steps.*

I make a bootable USB stick as follows under OS X on my MacBook.

```
diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2 
sudo dd if=./xubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
diskutil eject /dev/disk2
```

These commands create the bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on it. I plug it into my new machine with an h55m-E23 mainboard from MSI. After starting the machine, the mainboard will boot from the USB stick. I followed the install instruction on the screen. After I hit the install button, the machine starts installing the System on the SSD by first creating an ext4 filesystem like on every other machine.

After approximately 3 to 4 minutes the machine will crash and restart immediately or the machine will freeze my monitor output. This is the first time I install Linux on an SSD. I switched the IDE mode in the BIOS to AHCI mode. Still the same error.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I've installed different Linux like Arch or Debian or Ubuntu only on real harddrives and not on SSDs. And I've installed them with DVD or CD.

Comment: Does the "Try Ubuntu" environment work? Does the installer work on a VM on a different machine?

Comment: Yes "Try Ubuntu" works stable. The installer works on different machine.

Comment: Ok. I connect now my 250 GB Harddrive to the mainboard and still got the same crash when installing Xubuntu. After that i removed my r290 amd graficcard and connect my tv to the hdmi port on the mainboard. And still got the same error. I thing the mainboard is broken. I bought the mainboard used on ebay, the 4 gb ram is new and the powersupply is also new.